# .htaccess broke my ajax

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I tried a .htaccess to remove the index.php part of the url, and now the ajax content won’t load anymore, even if I remove the .htaccess. Here’s what the .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The error Chrome is giving me looks like this:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://jolinmasson.com/ajax/page:6?_=1397504793977
```

Comment: Was the ajax working before?

Comment: Yep. And there wasn’t even another .htaccess…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to get it working with that .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|md|mdown)$ error [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*) error [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^kirby/(.*) error [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```